# How to delete entries in riak using MapReduce/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, riak

I'm replacing a session manager from Django/MySQL to Go/Riak. I need to periodically check for expired sessions and delete them.

Any one knows how to delete a register using Riak's javascript/MapReduce using ?

Answer (score 0):

You could, in theory, initialize the internal erlang client with `{ok,C}=riak:local_connect()`, even inside a map or reduce phase, and then do `C:delete(<<"Bucket">>,<<"Key">>).` or whatever it is you need.

Comment: First, thank you for the reply.

I found multiple solutions using Erlang and a more or less good documentation in this technology. I wanted to avoid Erlang since I don't know the language and my routine is fairly complicated. Lacking something better I can map in Javascript and reduce using Erlang.

But still, if you know any good documentation on MapReduce Riak using Javascript I really appreciate it.

Comment: if I try this but couldn't delete elements for special types. I search for documentation but I found only the source in repo. Do you know how to do it or where this documentation?

Comment: No, need. I mimic [this](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/bucket-types/#Buckets-as-Namespaces) example and it works. Instead of `C:delete(<<"Bucket">>,<<"Key">>).` I use `C:delete({<<"maps">>, <<"Bucket">>}, <<"Key">>).`.